# Internal calculation of a quantum circuit

Tags: quantum-circuit, hadamard

Upto the below point, i [image]understand clearly..

But what happened after that, the phase value changes why? do not understand the internal calculations?
[image]

Comment: anyone plz help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's walk through the circuit one step at a time (Warning: my calculation has used the convention that the top wire, q[0], is the first in the tensor product.).

1. We start with every qubit in the state 0, so
   $$ |000\rangle.$$
2. Hadamard on every qubit
   $$\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}(|000\rangle+|001\rangle+|010\rangle+|011\rangle+|100\rangle+|101\rangle+|110\rangle+|111\rangle)$$
3. First Toffoli
   $$\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}(|000\rangle+|001\rangle+|010\rangle+|011\rangle+|100\rangle+|101\rangle+|111\rangle+|110\rangle)$$
4. $S$ gate
   $$\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}(|000\rangle+i|001\rangle+|010\rangle+i|011\rangle+|100\rangle+i|101\rangle+i|111\rangle+|110\rangle)$$
5. Second Toffoli
   $$\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}(|000\rangle+i|001\rangle+|010\rangle+i|011\rangle+|100\rangle+i|101\rangle+i|110\rangle+|111\rangle)$$
   Let's try and group some terms to make doing the final Hadamard easier
   $$\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}(\sqrt2|+00\rangle+i\sqrt2|+01\rangle+(|0\rangle+i|1\rangle)|10\rangle+(i|0\rangle+|1\rangle)|11\rangle)$$
6. We can now apply the last Hadamard
   $$\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}(\sqrt2|000\rangle+i\sqrt2|001\rangle+e^{i\pi/4}(|0\rangle-i|1\rangle)|10\rangle+e^{i\pi/4}(|0\rangle-i|1\rangle)|11\rangle)$$

If we read this off, we should get outcomes 010,110,011,111 with equal probability, and 000 and 001 with double that probability. However, I've calculated the action of the circuit using the convention that I'm used to (the opposite of what qiskit does). So, we actually have to reverse all the binary strings. Thus, 010,011,110,111 all come out with the same probability and 000 and 100 come out with double that.

Comment: Thnx for the detailed analysis..  just 1 thing i don't understand in the last line, when we apply the last H gate then how the term (|0⟩+i|1⟩) converted to eiπ/4(|0⟩−i|1⟩)?

Comment: You just have to do the maths:
$$\frac{1}{2}\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & -1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ i \end{bmatrix}=\frac{1}{2}\begin{bmatrix} 1+i \\ 1-i\end{bmatrix}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{bmatrix} e^{i\pi/4} \\ e^{-i\pi/4}\end{bmatrix}=e^{i\pi/4}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ e^{-i\pi/2} \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 0):

You are applying Hadamard gate on q[0] after CCX.  Whenever you apply H gate, it will make the qubit superposition. So the q[0] again went to superposition with 50% of probability for both |0> and |1> that is why you are seeing the states |000> and |100> have higher probability.